# Can't finish checkout, Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: magento2, checkout, api

I don't know what i do wrong, but when i tried to do checkout, there's an error and i can't finish the checkout. See the picture below for the detail.

**After click Place Order** :
[image: Error 1]

**Error on inspect element :**

[image: Error 2]

**Error on service :**

[image: Error 3]

Answer (score 0):

For these kinds of errors:

- Check your Magento log under `var/log` and `var/report` folders.
- If still not see any error, please check your server logs (Apache, Nginx)

Comment: I checked the var/report and found this `{main}";s:3:"url";s:67:"/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods-by-address-id";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}`, is that the error?

Comment: Did you check log under `var/log` folder?

Comment: Here's the thing in log exception file `[2017-11-06 01:46:16] main.CRITICAL: RuntimeException: Source class "" for "Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor" generation does not exist. in /var/www/html/xxxxxxxx.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:185`

Answer (score -1):

below are the few solutions which can help to resolve the problem.

1) Stores > Configuration > Customer > Customer Configuration > Name and Address Options: Number of Lines in a Street Address make it 2
please set it as 1

2) Please check your sales_sequence_meta and sales_sequence_profile tables
sales_sequence_profile
[image]

sales_sequence_meta
[image]

make sure both have correct value as per your current store id.
this will resolve the problem.

Please take below link as reference.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6929

Thanks